# Find the locus of $(a, b)$ for which the function $f(x)$ is continuous is $x=1$ and discontinuous at $x=2$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Find the locus of $(a, b)$ for which the function $f(x)$ is continuous is $x=1$ and discontinuous at $x=2$

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
    ax-b &x\le1\\
    3x &1<x<2\\
    bx^2-a &x\ge2
  \end{cases}$$

My attempt is as follows:-

$$f(1)=a-b$$
$$f(1^+)=\lim_{x\to1^+}3x$$
$$f(1^+)=3$$

$$f(1^-)=\lim_{x\to1^+}ax-b$$
$$f(1^-)=a-b$$

As function is continuous at $x=1$

$$a-b=3$$

$$y-x=3\tag{1}$$

$$f(2)=4b-a$$
$$f(2^+)=\lim_{x\to2^+}bx^2-a$$
$$f(2^+)=4b-a$$

$$f(2^-)=\lim_{x\to2^-}3x=6$$

$$4b-a\ne 6$$
$$4b-(b+3)\ne 6$$
$$b\ne 3, a\ne 6$$

Now what is the locus here?

By locus I understand the set of points sharing some property.

Locus of $(a,b)$ should be set of all points $(3+b,b)$ where $b\in R-\{3\}$

Is it correct? How can we formally define locus here?

Comment: The answer is correct. You could write the locus as $x-y=3,x\ne6$ where $x$ denotes $a$ and $y$ denotes $b$.

Answer (score 0):

On the $(a,b)$-plane, your locus is  the union of two rays (the straight line $(3+b,b)$ without a  point).